# Sqlite: How to insert variable into string in prepared statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I'm using a Java wrapper for accessing Sqlite but I assume this is a general Sqlite question.

```
String stmt = "SELECT foo FROM bah WHERE foo='%/?/%';
PreparedStatement a = myConn.prepareStatement(stmt);

a.setString(1, "hello");
a.executeQuery();
```

... throws an exception - it doesn't like the ? being inside quotes. Everything is fine if I do

```
...WHERE foo=?
```

but this isn't the statement I want.

How can I insert a variable into such a prepared statement? If you forget about the fact I'm using Sqlite, how is this is done using other database technologies?

Comment: Don't know the answer off the top of my head, but did you try doing setString(1, "%/hello%")?  You might have to munge your input string to surround it w/ %

Comment: I guess I could just do 

    ... WHERE foo=?

and

    a.setString(1, "\'%/hello%/\'");

as a last resort.

Comment: posted my comment before I saw your suggestion SB - thanks. I could do that but I'd still like to know if there's a nicer way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No database I've encountered will let you put a parameter inside a string literal. If this was supported, then you'd have to escape every `?` character in a string that wasn't a parameter.

You can, however, use string concatenation to support what you are after:

```
SELECT foo FROM bah WHERE foo = '%/' || ? || '/%'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the wildcard when setting the value:

```
String stmt = "SELECT foo FROM bah WHERE foo= ?"
PreparedStatement a = myConn.prepareStatement(stmt);
a.setString(1, "%hello%");
```